# How to replace only capturing groups with regex_replace in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I want to replace only the capturing groups `(\d{3})` with `xxx`, however when I run this code the whole expression changes to `xxx` and not only the given capturing groups.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main() {
 
    string editedNum = regex_replace("PN55-444-444-444-333",  regex (R"(PN55-(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{3})-\d{3})"), "xxx");
    cout<<"Edited number "<<editedNum;

}
```

I've tried the code above and the result is `xxx` however I want the result `PN55-xxx-xxx-xxx-333`. Can I use `regex_replace` to target only replace specific capturing groups?

Comment: You have braces around the entire expression, which treats that as a capture group aswell, changing the entire string to `xxx`. Try removing the surrounding braces.

Comment: Tried this ```regex_replace("PN55-444-444-444-333",  regex ("PN55-(\\d{3})-(\\d{3})-(\\d{3})-\\d{3}"), "xxx")``` and it gives the same result.

Comment: Where has `R` gone to, and why are your backslashed now escaped?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal I think `R"(` and `)"` are part of the raw string literal

Comment: I think regex_replace replaces anything that matches - not just the groups.  But you can't use a look behind with c++.  Boost Regex does support look behinds because it is PCRE.